# Soap Header with Authorization Basic in native PHP

Tags: php, soap, teradata, soap-client

i need to connect to TeraData SOAP API which now demands a Authorization Basic Header to be sent with the login credentials. I do not know how to adress the  problem. I got the access working in SoapUI when adding Basic Authorization Header - please can anyone help me to get the code straight:

Here's the Header SoapUI sends and the response is good:

```
POST http://example.com/api/soap/v6 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 302
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Authorization: Basic [user&pass-base64-encoded]
```

Here's how i am trying to set up my SoapClient:

```
$namespace =  "http://ecircle.com/developer/ecmapi";
$wsdl = "https://sslh.teradatadmc.com/teradata/api/soap/v6?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0));
$login = 'xxx';
$password = 'yyy';
$header = new SoapHeader($namespace, 'Authorization: Basic',   
base64_encode("$login:$password"));
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

it's not accepted and i just get an HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Error

The stacktrace shows me the header that i sent - the Authorization part is missing there.

```
public '__last_request_headers' => string 'POST /api/soap/v6 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.5.12
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 584
```

Comment: You need to use `base64_encode($login:$password)` first, and then check for other errors, because the syntaxt you are using will not work.

Comment: i follow your suggestion - but it keeps me giving  - `(Exception) => null
  public 'faultstring' => string 'Unauthorized' (length=12)
  public 'faultcode' => string 'HTTP' (length=4)` - is it possible to send standard http-headers with the soap call as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

man i was so stupid:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0,
                     "login" => $login, "password" => $password) );
```

[For HTTP authentication, the login and password options can be used to supply credentials.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

Answer (score -1):

That's because you should encode your login credentials this way:

```
base64_encode("$login:$password")
```

instead of: 
`base64_encode($login) . ':' . base64_encode($password)`

Comment: No - i tried that as well - doesn't help. But thanks.