# Soap authentification failed

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm used to writing PHP code for a SOAP call
and this is my code

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient("http://www.fma.fr/webservices_comparateurs/tarification_sante_comparateurs.asmx?wsdl");
   $param = array('NomUtilisateur' => 'XXXXXX','MotDePasse' => 'XXYYZZ','ContenuDuMessage' => '');
   $values = $client->TariferSante($param);

    var_dump($values);

?>
```

### when i execute the script I get an authentification error message:

> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["TariferSanteResult"]=> string(109)
>   "err_authentification" }

the used parameters are true, you can try with this link:
http://www.fma.fr/webservices_comparateurs/tarification_sante_comparateurs.asmx?op=TariferSante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated Answer : 
i tried this code and it worked

```
$options = array(
    'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
    'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
    'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'connection_timeout'=>15,
    'trace'=>true,
    'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
    'exceptions'=>true,

);

class TariferSante {

    public $nomUtilisateur;
    public $motDePasse;
    public $contenuDuMessage;
}
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.fma.fr/webservices_comparateurs/tarification_sante_comparateurs.asmx?wsdl",$options);

$param = new TariferSante();
$param->nomUtilisateur = "XXXXXXX";
$param->motDePasse = "XXYYZZ";
$param->contenuDuMessage = "";
$values = $client->TariferSante($param);
echo "Request".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest());

var_dump($values);
```

Comment: this is not working, i get the same error: object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["TariferSanteResult"]=> string(109) "err_authentification" }

Comment: ok try the following
     $client->__soapCall("TariferSante", $param);

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with Teradata Soap, i think it needs Basic Authorisation over http - my solution was:

```
  $opts = array();
  $opts['login'] = 'username';
  $opts['password'] = 'secretpassword';
  $opts['trace'] = 1;
  $opts['authentication'] = SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC;
  $url = "https://example.com/vx?wsdl";
  $client = new SoapClient($url, $opts);
```

i got it working with that.

Check my discussion here: [Soap Header with Authorization Basic in native PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360282/soap-header-with-authorization-basic-in-native-php/35380647#35380647)