# Extract SOAP Specific Values And Return in PHP

Tags: soap, soap-client

Im new to SOAP UI, so is there any method to extract specific values from SOAP UI and return in PHP i want to extract data from this Courier Service Tracking SOAP API and show it in PHP

SOAP API : http://webapp.tcscourier.com/codapi/Service1.asmx
SOAP Request : http://webapp.tcscourier.com/codapi/Service1.asmx?op=GetCNDetailsByReferenceNumber

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might want to do is:

First you init a connection to the remote soap-Server, therefore you need to initiate a client

`$client = new SoapClient('http://webapp.tcscourier.com/codapi/Service1.asmx?WSDL');`

Since its a public API you don't need Login Credentials

Then you want to call the remote Method, e.g. getAllCities and store the response in a variable;

`$response = $client->getAllCities();`

Now you can view the result:

`var_dump($response);`

To be sure nothing wents wrong you can put the code above in `try...error`

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://webapp.tcscourier.com/codapi/Service1.asmx?WSDL');
try {

  $response = $client->getAllCities();

} catch (SoapFault $e) {

 var_dump($e);    

}
```

HTH - best regards,
Lupo

Comment: Thanks but i want to use the function "GetCNDetailsByReferenceNumber" which requires username / password and a reference ID can you please guide me how i can i add these as well

Comment: the login is usually handled via an array passed to the SoapClient:

`$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0,
                     "login" => $login, "password" => $password) );`

You can find more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360282/soap-header-with-authorization-basic-in-native-php/35380647#35380647 or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908373/soap-authentification-failed/37926352#37926352

the latter also shows a good example how to usually pass arguments to the SoapClient